# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InternalError: ERROR: constraint xxxxxxxxxx is not a foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql

I did not get convincing answers in similar question asked. Could anyone answer what could possibly cause this type of error? I would be very thankful.

```
INSERT INTO roles ("name", "description", "organization_id", "created_at", "updated_at") 
VALUES ('role_name',NULL, 69, now(),now());
```

Here, organization_id is foreign key referencing table: organizations(id)

> ERROR: constraint *15362041* is not a foreign key constraint

Querying into pg_constraint:

```
oid             conname                        connamespace   contype

**15362041**   RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_745708   2200           t

**15362043**   RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_745709   2200           t
```

Querying into pg_trigger:

```
oid        tgconstraint tgrelid   tgname

15362042  **15362041**   12731707  RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_745708

15362044  **15362043**   12731707  RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_745709
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show us what you've done to get this error message?

Comment: `INSERT INTO roles ("name", "description", "organization_id", "created_at", "updated_at")
values('role_name',NULL, 69, now(),now());` Here, organization_id is foreign key referencing table: organizations(id)